How exactly does Proof of History makes Solana's Proof of Work faster?
I am reading this blogpost https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-slots-blocks-and-epochs and it says:

A key innovation in Solana's PoS is its integration with Proof of History (PoH), which serves as a verifiable and reliable source of time. PoH acts as a clock for the network, helping to keep track of events and their order. By using PoH as a foundation, Solana's PoS system can streamline the decision-making process, resulting in faster and more efficient transactions, while still maintaining a secure and decentralized network.

I have a slight understanding of PoH but not fully so I am not sure how it integrates with Solan's PoS making it faster.
An explanation would be appreciated.
